# Error en push git

Tags: git, push, bitbucket

Buen día alguien me ayuda con esto, estoy intentando hacer un push pero me genera el siguiente error, ya he intentado hacerlo de todas las maneras.

git push
remote: The requested repository either does not exist or you do not have access. If you believe this repository exists and you have access, make sure you're authenticated.

Comment: Pregunta obvia, pero igual hay que hacerla: ¿Verificaste lo que dice el error?

Comment: Ya resolviste el problema amigo?

Comment: La url del repositorio cambió, sigue los pasos de mi respuesta

Answer (score 0):

Su URL de git podría haber cambiado. Cambie la URL en el directorio local usando el siguiente comando

para el protocolo https

git remote set-url origin https://github.com/username/repository.git
para el protocolo ssh

git remote set-url origin git@github.com:username/repository.git

Este podria ser la solución